# aurora mysql load from s3 specify file extension

Tags: mysql, amazon-s3, amazon-aurora

I have files with different extensions in my S3 bucket. I would like to load  only `CSV` extension. Is there a way to specify this in the `LOAD FROM S3` command?

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraMySQL.Integrating.LoadFromS3.html), there is a way to specify the `PREFIX` and load the files. This works for my case as all my CSV files have a specific prefix. However, I have not seen a way to specify the `SUFFIX`.

Here is the command I used:

```
LOAD DATA FROM S3 PREFIX 's3://bucket_name/folder_name/filename_prefix' 
..... (options)
```